# LocalTime does not parse 00:00 correctly

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-time, localdate

I am trying to parse "Mon 00:00-23:59" using `LocalTime`.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("23:59", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
```

But, `start.isBefore(end)` returns true, how is this possible?

I am trying to compare the Localtimes to check after parsing the user input that start will always be before end, otherwise it should throw an error to the user.

**Solved :** I realise that this requires LocalDateTime or Date in order to compare the days as well, since there are corner cases such as 00:00.

Comment: hint: `00:00` does not mean midnight today. It means start of today, so the result you are getting is correct

Comment: How is 00:00 on Monday _not_ before 23:59 on Monday?

Comment: I got no idea what you are asking. I downvoted and voted to close. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69776883/edit) your question to answer the question by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-, and I will seriously consider retracting my votes.

Comment: @OleV.V. Arvind Kumar Avinash got my question and answered it correctly

Comment: Thanks for replying to my criticism. That’s good for you and bad for the rest of us. Stack Overflow is meant to be a resource for eveyone to enjoy. When we can’t understand the question, it makes things a lot harder for us. I repeat: please edit your question and make it clear what the expected result was and how you got to expect that result. Would that be hard to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

- The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards. Your time strings are in ISO 8601 format.
- The local time, `00:00` corresponds to `12:00 AM` whereas `23:59` corresponds to `11:59 PM`, it's obvious that `00:00` is before `23:59`. So, the results that you have got is correct.

To avoid confusion, I recommend you attach a date with the local time i.e. use `LocalDateTime`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("00:00");
        LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("23:59");

        System.out.println(start.format(dtf));
        System.out.println(end.format(dtf));

        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();

        LocalDateTime ldtStart = start.atDate(today);
        LocalDateTime ldtEnd = end.atDate(today);
        System.out.println(ldtStart);
        System.out.println(ldtEnd);

        // Notice the result when you add a minute to ldtEnd
        System.out.println(ldtEnd.plusMinutes(1));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12:00 AM
11:59 PM
2021-10-30T00:00
2021-10-30T23:59
2021-10-31T00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/drOkvV)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Your issue has nothing to do with parsing.

And, the behavior you see is a feature, not a bug.

[`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) represent the time of day for a single imaginary generic 24-hours-long day. That day starts at 00:00:00.0. So all other values are *after* that zero time value.

So this should return `true`:

```
LocalTime.parse( "00:00" ).isBefore( LocalTime.parse( "23:59" ) )  // true.
```

Be aware that in our politically-defined timekeeping systems days are not necessarily 24-hours long, nor do they necessarily start at 00:00. Some days may be 23, 23.5, 25, or other number of hours long. And some dates in some time zones may start at a time such as 01:00.

By the way, notice there is no need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` when the input complies with ISO 8601 standard for date-time textual values.

Comment: I see, so how I can parse 00:00 as 12 midnight?